# Codenvy graphical output with Python?

Tags: python, codenvy

I'm trying to get familiar with codenvy IDE. I work with matplotlib to view some graphical results but it seems this cloud IDE doesn't support an output window with any visuals. Is there a way to view anything except text in terminal window or I should switch to other IDE's?

p.s. I'm trying to plot few lines on a coordinate plane (x, y). Doesn't really matter what to plot, just trying to understand if it's possible to view anything related to graphics in Codenvy.

Comment: Please add some example of what you need to visualize

Comment: Anything from plotting tutorial http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html